# Not understanding universal generalisation, and proof that uses it

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

From $\varphi$ follows $\forall x \varphi$.

E.g., universal generalizations of the formula $Rxy \wedge \exists z Sz$ can be $\forall x (Rxy \wedge \exists z Sz)$, $\forall x \forall y \forall u(Rxy \wedge \exists z Sz)$ etc.

I can't grasp why it is possible to do this, who says that in  $\forall x (Rxy \wedge \exists z Sz)$ you just can say that it applies to *all* x's?

Then there is this proof:

Axiom schema's used in the proof:

1 $(\forall x (\varphi \rightarrow \psi))\rightarrow (\forall x \varphi \rightarrow \forall  x \psi)$
2 $\varphi \rightarrow \forall x \varphi$
3 $\forall x \varphi \rightarrow [t/x]\varphi$

$\Sigma = \{Sa, \forall x (Sa \rightarrow Sx)\}$. Proof $\Sigma \vdash \forall x Sx$


1 $\Sigma \vdash Sa$
2 $\Sigma \vdash \forall x (Sa \rightarrow Sx)$
3 $\vdash \forall (Sa \rightarrow Sx) \rightarrow (Sa \rightarrow Sy)$ axiom 3, *t* = *y*
4 $\Sigma \vdash Sa \rightarrow Sy$
5 $\Sigma \vdash Sy$
6 $\Sigma \vdash \forall x Sx$

Why does $(Sa \rightarrow Sx)$ need to change to $(Sa \rightarrow Sy)$ in 3? And what and why is happening at step 5 and 6? From $Sy$ to $\forall x Sx$??

Thanks to Mauro and Berci; I wish I could upvote you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $x$ denotes a general *indeterminant* (and not a constant), so if you can *derive a proof* of a formula, using the indeterminant $x$ in it, then the same proof will work when $x$ is replaced by anything else throughout.

A) If we think about semantics, i.e. the *meaning* of these formulas, then we can assign values to the variables, and a formula is said to be valid in an interpretation context ('*model*') if it is satisfied with respect to *all* possible evaluation of the variables.

This leads to the rule of universal generalisation in formal logic: $\phi(x,y)$ is *regarded* valid iff $\forall x,y:\phi(x,y)$ holds.

B) In step 3 we applied axiom 3 for $\varphi=\ (Sa\to Sx)$ and $t=y$, i.e. we substitute $y$ in place of $x$ in $\varphi$ (that is $[y/x]\varphi$).

The meaning of axiom 3 is that if a formula $\varphi$ holds for all $x$, then it can be specialized to anything else: whatever we write in place of $x$, the formula will be true.

From step 5 to step 6 we simply apply the generalization rule, which is axiom 2, used with variable $y$. 
 Well, yes, we would obtain $\forall y Sy$ by that.
If we want to strictly continue to get it with $x$, apply axioms 3 and 2 again:

> $\,$7. $\Sigma\vdash Sx $ by axiom 3. for $\forall y\,Sy$. 
>   $\,$8. $\Sigma\vdash \forall x\,Sx$ by axiom 2.

Comment: B) It is odd, I wish the authors would've mentioned anything like this in the book. As I mentioned to Mauro who also wrote an answer, the substitution could be done as well with $[x/x]$, no confusion needed!

Comment: Yes, I think, you are right. However, it is not standard to use the same variable in a bounded part and also free in the same formula.

Answer (score 2):

*1)* Quantifying variables not contained in the formula which is in the scope of the quantifier has no effect; see your example :

> $∀x∀y∀u(Rxy∧∃zSz)$;

$u$ is not into $Rxy$ nor into $\exists z Sz$ : thus, it has **no** effect.

*2)* who says that in $∀x(Rxy∧∃zSz)$ you just can say that it applies to all $x$'s?

This question is not clear to me; the *syntax* of first-order logic "force us" to consider that the $x$ into the *scope* of a quantifier $\forall x$ must "range over" **all** the objects in the domain of the interpretation.

*3)* about your proof : in step 3, you apply Ax.3 : $∀xφ→[t/x]φ$. In the proof, we have that $\phi$ is $(Sa→Sx)$; thus $∀xφ$ is $∀x(Sa→Sx)$.

$(Sa→Sy)$ is $[y/x](Sa→Sx)$, where the *variable* $y$ is used as the *term* $t$.

*Terms* are : individual *variables*, like : $x,y,...$, individual *constants*, like $0$ in arithmetic), "complex terms", like $x+0$ in arithmetic.

In step 5, the proof uses *modus ponens* (or detachement : from $\phi$ and $\phi \rightarrow \psi$, infer $\psi$).

Thus, from 1) : $Sa$, and 4) : $Sa→Sy$, he deduces $Sy$.

Step 6 is derived form step 5 according to Ax.2 (called also *Generalization rule* : if $\vdash \phi$, then $\vdash \forall x \phi$).

Comment: If you have $Rxy \wedge \exists z Sz$, why not $\exists x (Rxy \wedge \exists z Sz)$? Why must it be $\forall x (Rxy \wedge \exists z Sz)$? There is nothing to my knowledge that lets my say "this applies to *all*" x's.

Comment: About 3) I understand, but to me it is not clear as to why it must be so that $x$ must be changed into $y$. The proof could just as well be done *without* doing this: $[x/x]$. Even stranger, from 5 to 6, it is changed back again to $x$!

Comment: @GarthMarenghi - "There is nothing to my knowledge that lets my say "this applies to all" x's."... It depends on you: on what you are saying... If you want to express : "all balls are black", you need : "for all x, if Ball(x), then Black(x)". If you want to say : "there is a white ball", you need : "exists an x such that Ball(x) and White(x)".

Comment: @GarthMarenghi - you are right - For all x means that you can "instantiate" it with a "name" (a *term*) whatever; thus, $y$ and $x$ and ... are all good. If you have found the proof into a textbook, I think that the author thinks that it is "more easy" to grasp if he cange the variable ... It seems not so.

Comment: Right, but universal instantiation says this: From $\varphi$ follows $\forall x \varphi$. The choice doesn't seem up to me, it is something that is ready for use.

Comment: It is from a textbook indeed, and after the third round through the book, I still can't find and still couldn't come up with a reasonable explanation.

Comment: I think the point is that $x$ is an indeterminate.

Comment: Yes, yes. See my updated answer. You can substitute anything in place of $x$.